# Русский мат в 19 - начале 20 века

Tags: обсценная-лексика, словари

Играю в ролевую, сюжет разворачивается в период сразу после революции, но прям точный год не определён. Моему персонажу просто необходимо отборно ругаться, но, если какие-то необычные ругательства, подходящие под временной отрезок, в интернете я нашёл, то именно с матом труднее. Пытался найти какой-нибудь словарь мата на это время, но нашёл лишь шуточный, а другие уже более поздние. Не могу быть уверен, какие слова можно использовать, а какие тогда ещё не вошли в употребление.
Если кто-нибудь знает такие словари или научные работы — буду очень признателен.